# time interval period in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

How to display the time period of the most widely in use in ms sql server

I have purchase data, such as:

```
hours   the number of purchases
10:00       2
12:00       4
13:00       5
14:00       1
```

I want to show the period of time with most buyers. So the results would be with the most purchases hour period between 12:00 to 13:00.

Here is my query :

```
select  h.hours, day(d.dates)
from hours h, dates d
group by h.hours, day(d.dates)
having count(h.hours) >= all (select count(h2.hours) 
from hours h2, dates d2
group by h2.hours, day(d2.dates))
```

but the result is: 13:00

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What did you expect the result to be?

Comment: I want the result  :   12:00 - 13:00

Comment: What is criteria for "the period of time with the most buyers"? Why do you want 12:00-13:00 but not 13:00 or 10:00-13:00?

Comment: because i want to display a clock that has the largest purchases. in this case there are  12:00 --> 4 and 13:00 --> 5, 
so I want the result 12:00 - 13:00

Answer (score 1):

You have incorrectly modeled your purchase data, partly because you tried to store a calculated value (10:00, 12:00, 13:00) rather than rely on the raw data (datetime).

**Consider your reporting requirements when designing the data model**

Here's one way to solve your current problem

You could have a base Purchases table with a sequential Purchase_No, a DateTime field and a unique Product_Id (you might also want a Quantity field for example)

When a purchase is made, this is the table that is populated with a new record

```
Table: Purchases
Purchase_No, Purchase_DateTime, Product_Id, Quantity
```

For your 'Hourly Purchases Report' you could populate your report dataset using this query

```
Select DayOf(p.PurchaseDateTime), HourOf(p.PurchaseDateTime), count(p.*)
From Purchases p
Group By DayOf(p.PurchaseDateTime), HourOf(p.PurchaseDateTime)
Order By count(p.*) Desc
```

Now your answer will be 12:00 instead of 13:00. All purchases that have an Hour value of 12:00 obviously happened sometime between 12:00 and 13:00.

You don't need **12:00-13:00**, you just need **12:00** on a *reliable* **hourly** report.

*I'm not sure about how to implement HourOf and DayOf on your DBMS of choice, that shouldn't be too hard to figure out.*